# Python - replace \n and replace \t - interesting behaviour

Tags: python, replace

Here is my example:

```
test = 'some string\n'
test.replace('\n',' ')
test.replace('\t',' ')
```

I cannot understand why output looks like

```
'some string\n'
```

`'\n'` should have disappeared.

Comment: `replace` doesn't replace in place.

Comment: try `test = test.replace("\n", " ")`

Comment: `replace()` returns a new string, it does not modify the existing string.

Comment: If I can say something - more as a tip - if u want to 'replace' tabs, enters with spaces, u can just go for `test = ' '.join('some\t test string\n'.split())`